# How to setup mysql via bash without entering the password?

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

I am setting password like this:

```
  echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password "root" | debconf-set-selections
  echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password "root" | debconf-set-selections
```

When I want to do something like this:

```
 mysql -u root -p -e 'DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User="";'
```

Please note that the query itself is not the problem right now. I want to be able to run the query through bash without entering password, but as it is right now it still asks for password.

Also tried:  mysql -u root -p root -e 'DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User="";'

Still, no luck. Also tried to set no password:

```
 echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password "" | debconf-set-selections
  echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password "" | debconf-set-selections
```

but it seems like it still prompts for password.

Answer (score 1):

Remove whitespace between `-p` and your password.